# Can't load PHP code in PHP if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar, slug

I'm using Wordpress for my new website. Now I've added four special sidebars for every page on my website. And I'm trying to use the slug from every page to activate the sidebar for that page. I know you've also got plugins to do this for you. But I want it to be all automatic. :)

I know how to call the webpage slug. You can do this with the following php code:

```
<?php the_slug();?>
```

And I know I can call the sidebar for each page with the following code:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'SIDEBAR-NAME-FOR-THAT-PAGE ' ) )  {?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    //empty
<?php } ?>
```

But now the thing. I've named my sidebars the same as the different slugs for every page. So I want the SIDEBAR-NAME to be the same as the slug. So I need to call this:

```
<?php the_slug();?>
```

on the place for the SIDEBAR-NAME-FOR-THAT-PAGE in the example above. I already tried this:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( ' 'tag=' the_slug() ' ) )  {?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    //empty
<?php } ?>
```

But nothing seems to happend.

Anyone? Would be great! Thanks already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to familiar with WP, but I think you should write it this way.

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'tag=' . the_slug() ) ) { ?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    //empty
<?php } ?>
```

or maybe this way

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( the_slug() ) ) { ?>
    <ul id="sidebar">
       <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php } else { ?>
    //empty
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Really awesome! Your second solutions works almost great! The only thing is that I see the slug before the sidebar. [Click here for an example](http://cl.ly/image/0I3U1K1A3j2t) Do you also know how this could have happend? Or better; how to solve it.